# Не понимаю почему ошибка, только начинаю изучать питон, помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: python

[image: слева код, справа ошибка]

Только начал учить питон и столкнулся с такой ошибкой

Comment: Напишите код текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int(input(...))` надо писать только в том случае если будет вводится число.В вашем случае надо написать просто `input()`

Также `input`в отличие от `print` принимает только один аргумент. вам надо объединить несколько строк, это можно сделать с помощью f-строк

```
input(f"hello {s}")
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)

Answer (score 0):

Ну начнем с того что `int` это число а вводимый текст (в данном случае имя) это `str`. Как нам всем известно python не любит смешивание типов данных

`int()` - исполбзуеться для превращение текста (если он состоит только из чисел) в цифру

`str()` - превращает же число или другой тип данных в текст